# Creating a .txt file in C++ with variables

Tags: c++, variables, text, char

So I'm designing a game where data is stored and read with text files. But I need to be able to do this in a repeating fashioned so the names of the text files need to be different for each one procedurally. I figured that using variables as the name would solve this issue but I am having a hard time doing this and getting the compiler to work with it.
This is my current code to write 'hello' to a text file named 'test.txt':

`ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("test.txt");
myfile << "hello";
myfile.close();`

Now, I can replace "test.txt" with a single char* pointer or char array buffer, but I need to separate the name of the file with the .txt extension.
The idea that I had was to somehow combine a char* variable for a name reference (Such as galaxy, star, planet, etc.), plus a numeric value (would have to be a big number, perhaps a double or float), plus the ".txt" text extension. This would then be one char pointer or array that would be compatible with myfile.open. Any ideas? I'm open to changing the process of this as long as I get the same end result.

Comment: Have you considered strings ?

Comment: I should also mention that whenever I try and use a string instead of a char* or char[] in myfile.open() that the compiler comes up with errors stating that you can't convert between strings and const char's.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider [`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/?kw=string) instead of `char*` for your filename, as C++11 allows both types:

```
string myfilename="test"; 
myfile.open(myfilename+".txt");
myfile << "hello";
myfile.close();
```

To create more complex filenames you could then consider to use [stringstreams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/): you can easily combine and format the filename using the usual output fromatting unctions/operators, and convert it to a string.

```
stringstream nn;
int counter=0; 
nn<<myfilename<<counter<<".txt";
myfile.open(nn.str());
...
```

Comment: I tried to use strings before, but I had issues with getting it to work, seems that I was missing some syntax.
So I tried your code:

`stringstream nn;
int counter=0;
string myfilename;
nn<<myfilename<<counter<<".txt";
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(nn.str());
myfile << "hello";
myfile.close();`

But I get an error:
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type)'

The error is addressing the myfile.open line.

Comment: Found the issue, had to use .c_str() instead of .str(). But this version only works with strings, so I just need to either find a way to convert stringstreams to strings, or find a way to convert numbers into strings without stringstreams.

Comment: Found a workaround of applying .str() to the stringstream and all works, ty for replies!

Comment: I can imagine that some headers were missing, because I had no problem compiling this code (see [online demo](http://ideone.com/5zgmk3)).  Happy to see that it finally helped :-)  An advice: *If you have issues with strings, you MUST come to solve them, because it's really needed if you want to write good and reliable C++ code.*